# Creating Web Application for Corda Nodes Login

Tags: corda

I have separated out the web servers from corda application.
I created a demo spring web application and moved REST APIs to web controller layer.

I am getting NodeRPCConnection using hard coded [for now] username/password/host/port. [hardcoded in properties file]

Now I have to implement production-grade User-Authentication/Login through web application.

I Would like to know ,

1. Whether there will be one web application require per corda node ?
   or one web application serving all corda nodes ?
2. What are the recommendations/ suggestions for implementation of user
       authentication/login [rpcuser].?

   3. If i have separate system users , how do i map them to rpcusers ?
      do i need to create a separate db in middle layer for this mapping ?

To access corda node we always need to get NodeRPcConnection before invoking different flows.
so How we should move incoming traffic [ Dynamically ] to particular corda node ?

Any suggestions / guidelines will be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: 1. One web application require per corda node
2. Create OAuth2 server

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you plan to run lots of nodes yourself? It's really up to you how you structure this - there's no one right answer. If your nodes are run by different organisations then they'd run one web server internally for each of them.

If you're running lots of nodes on behalf of others, you would probably use a separate RPC connection for each potential identity that's being controlled from the web app, as we're working on support for multiple identities per node so in future you would only need one node, and you'd be able to act as different identities by using different RPC users.